# How could I add another column which calculates the proportion over the total of some column of the selected table in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am doing with a table called HumanResources.Employee from schema AdventureWorks2017. It shows like this:

[image: image1].

And among the 16 columns I focus on OrganizationLevel and JobTitle. Then I count the number of those who have the same Organization Level and Job Title and select a new table:

```
SELECT
    OrganizationLevel,
    JobTitle,
    COUNT(*) AS Counts
FROM HumanResources.Employee AS tb1
GROUP BY
    OrganizationLevel,
    JobTitle;
```

and is the result:

[image: image2]

What I want is to add a column into this table (tb1). In the new column it is the proportion.

I have tried this:

```
SELECT *, tb1.Counts / SUM(tb1.Counts) 
FROM 
(
    SELECT OrganizationLevel, JobTitle, COUNT(*) as Counts
    FROM HumanResources.Employee AS tb1
    GROUP BY OrganizationLevel, JobTitle
)
```

However, the error message shows:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1

What is the correct command? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a window function for this.  Basically, you need to sum the counts over all the rows:

```
SELECT OrganizationLevel, JobTitle,
       COUNT(*) AS Counts,
       100.0 * COUNT(*) / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () 
FROM HumanResources.Employee e
GROUP BY OrganizationLevel, JobTitle;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But could you tell me what causes the problem with my original command?

Comment: @TangmingLi . . . You are mixing aggregation functions with non aggregation functions.  You want window functions.